# PHP not working after upgrading to PHP7 (Mac OS)

Tags: php, macos, apache

I recently upgraded php to version 7 using home-brew. After upgrading everything appeared fine, php_info() returned the correct version and everything worked as expected.

Today however, upon restarting my computer I was unable to access my localhost.

I ran: apachectl configtest

And got the following error:

/private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf: No such file or directory

I checkout the directory listed above and saw the file, but it was empty, upon deleting it localhost was working and the syntax returned okay. However, not php does not execute, it simply shows the code for the page.

At this point I'm fairly confident that both apache and php are both running, the check for apache returns syntax okay and running php -v returns the correct version I have set up in my path.

I'm assuming that the .conf file is important for some reason, but I'm not familiar with its function and how to set it up correctly.

Comment: Note sure if it helps at all, but I've got a file named `/private/etc/apache2/other/php5.conf` with these contents: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kAzixLwk). It looks like apache config. Maybe you can adapt it for PHP 7 or even just straight up copy, paste and rename it.

Comment: I hope this to  links can help you: http://superuser.com/questions/827937/apache-problems-after-upgrading-to-yosemite  and https://discussions.apple.com/message/30400405